# Car not starting after few kilometers of driving (Chevy Cruze 1.8L 2011)

Tags: starting, chevrolet, fuel-system, fuel-pump, cruze

I have a 2011 Chevy Cruze 1.8L

It starts fine when the engine is cold, however, after driving for a while then stopping it, it won't start.  One day I drove it 25 km, stopped it, then tried to start it again, but when I applied the throttle the engine chokes and dies.

My only guess is the fuel system somewhere - maybe the fuel pump?  Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: A little late , but  What was your problem at the end? and the solution if you came up to a fix

Answer (score 1):

It could be a clogged fuel filter, or a temperature sensor that has failed making the Air/Fuel Ratio too lean for restart on a "hot" engine.